# Disable session timeout in just one jsp in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-aui

I have set the session timeout in my Liferay 6.x to ten minutes and works great, but now I need to override it to a larger value in just one page of the web, as it has a pretty long read and my customers can't finnish it.

Is there any magic javascript, or maybe I need to move that jsp to a different portlet by itself, or what?

EDIT: There's an AUI().ready in a main.js, maybe there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Liferay.Session.extend()` in loop every let's say 9 minutes from javascript until user leaves this webpage